# Bluetooth and WIFI control while in kiosk mode

Tags: raspbian, kiosk

I am working on a project to allow access to a webpage in kiosk mode but would like it to be accessible outside of the setup environment so would like on screen control for WiFi and Bluetooth options so that they can be changed. I would like to know if this is possible to do while in kiosk mode. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Your post makes no sense. The whole point of kiosk mode is that there is no user access.